# Applying some changes in a tab separated text file using AWK

Tags: linux, shell, file, text, awk

I have a tab separated text file like this small example:

small example:

```
#type   cNA NA  me  ion Dir Mism    Bulge
X   GAAGC   GAAGa   chr8    3997355     -   5   0
X   GAAGC   GAAGC   chr8    11720692    +   5   0
X   GAAGC   GAAGC   chr8    23414961    -   5   0
```

and would like to make a new file like this expected output in which the 1st line is removed and columns are re-organised in this order:

```
1) columns 1 and 8 are removed.
2) 2nd column (small example file) moved to 1st column (expected output).
3) 4th column moved to the 2nd column.
4) 5th column moved to 3rd column.
5) 3rd column moved to 4th column.
6) 6th column moved to 5th column.
7) 7th column moved to 6th column.
```

here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
GAAGC   chr8    3997355     GAAGa   -   5
GAAGC   chr8    11720692    GAAGC   +   5
GAAGC   chr8    23414961    GAAGC   -   5
```

I am trying to do that in `AWK` using the following command:

```
awk -F '\t' '{ print $2 $4 $5 $3 $6 $7}' infile.txt > output.txt
```

but the results I am getting is not like expected output. do you know how to fix the code?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are re-assigning the fields? When we can simply print them like:

```
awk 'FNR==1{next} {print $2,$4,$5,$3,$6,$7}' Input_file
```

OR to add a tab separated output use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} FNR==1{next} {print $2,$4,$5,$3,$6,$7}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'FNR>1{print $2,$4,$5,$3,$6,$7}' Input_file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} FNR>1{print $2,$4,$5,$3,$6,$7}' Input_file
```

---

---

In case OP willing to use field re-assignment approach only then one could try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
FNR==1{
  next
}
{
  $1=$2
  $2=$4
  $4=$3
  $3=$5
  $5=$6
  $6=$7
  $7=$8=""
  sub(/ +$/,"")
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks. but I want to make tab separated file.

Comment: you will also need to set OFS to tab

Comment: @user10657934, Kindly check now once?